# C3P0 Connection Pool not working in Servlet/Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, connection-pooling, c3p0

Created a Datasource class based on C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource class. It works with testing code but won't work in servlet under tomcat container. Does anyone know why?

```
class Datasource{
   private ComboPooledDataSource cpds;
   private Datasoruce datasource;

   private Datasource(){
   //setup cpds
   cpds.new ComboPooledDataSource();
   cpds.setUser("abcd");
   ...
 }

 public static getInstance(){
     if( datasource == null ) datasource = new Datasource();
     return datasource;
 }

  public Connection getConnection(){
     return cpds.getConnection();
 }
}

//test code works if put in indepedent main() with multithreading.
  Datasource ds = Datasource.getInstance();
  Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

//Above test code won't work if put inside servlet doGet() with tomcat.
```

The error is "An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out right at the line of getConnection().

Comment: Put the exact error message in quotes and then copypaste the whole thing into that [input](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22An+attempt+by+a+client+to+checkout+a+Connection+has+timed+out%22) field far right-top of the current page and press [enter]. Now, which one of those was most helpful in solving the problem? If no one of them is, can you tell how exactly not?

Comment: The exact exception at ds.getConnection():                                 
"java.sql.SQL.Exception: An attemp by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out"
I set the timeout to 3 seconds. The point is, the same code works fine if I use an indepedent java program (with static main). It just does not work with tomcat/servlet env.
But If I use tomcat context.xml to configure C3P0 and use JNDI to access the data source, it works too.
So I just want to find out why the above implementation does not work under tomcat/servlet.